# Lightning?full node question

Tags: lightning-network, full-node

I'm running a full node as well as a Lightning Node with 4 channels open. I also have incoming ports enabled. I've noticed that my balance varies daily by a few thousand Sats. I'm new to running a node so wondered if someone could explain why this happens (or maybe link me to an article explaining).

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If it is only the balance of your channels that is changing I would assume that your node is routing payments. The lightning network is all about forwarding payments.

So the following explains what could have happened assuming you have two channels to a node A and a node B:

> (A)--20sat------40sat--(you)--30sat------50sat--(B)

meaning:

- node A has 20 satoshi
- your node has 40 satoshi + 30 satoshi = 70 Satoshi
- node B has 50 satoshi

Let us assume B wants to pay 15 satoshi to A this does work via lightning and via your node. The channels will update their balance:

> (A)--35sat------25sat--(you)--45sat------35sat--(B)

meaning:

1. node A has 35 satoshi
2. List item
3. your node has 25 satoshi + 45 satoshi = 70 Satoshi
4. node B has 35 satoshi

Probably your node even takes some routing fee which could have a standard value of at least one satoshi in that case your final balance would look like this

> (A)--35sat------25sat--(you)--46sat------34sat--(B)

meaning:

- node A has 35 satoshi
- your node has 25 satoshi + 46 satoshi = 71 Satoshi
- node B has 34 satoshi